# Extract text from a line that is between two elements using Cheeriogs

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, cheerio

The Cheeriogs library (`1ReeQ6WO8kKNxoaA_O0XEQ589cIrRvEBA9qcWpNqdOP17i47u6N9M5Xh0`) for Google App Script is in this GitHub repository:
https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs

I'm trying to collect the line of text that contains the value:

```
Total volume for this match in Betfair: 6387 �
```

[image]

For this I'm trying to use the following path:

```
$('td > p br:nth-child(2)');
sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue($(element).nextSibling.text().trim());
```

From what I understand in other questions answered here in the community, I should use `nextSibling` so that when extracting it it looks for the first value after the `<br>` tag indicated, but my attempt returned a blank value.

How should I proceed in these cases in order to collect the desired amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this suffice?

```
$(str).children()[2].next.data.trim()
```

[image: test]

First time using cheerio so please correct me if i'm wrong.